# move_base global costmap is not updated when removing an object/obstacle from the environment

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-melodic, global-costmap, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone!

I am currently working on a project using the ROS 1 navigation stack and for the past few weeks I have been struggling with this issue regarding the proper updating of move_base's global costmap when removing an obstacle from the static map. In this situation the mapping is done using the slam-toolbox package. The issue appears when switching from mapping mode to localization mode. While mapping, all the obstacles are marked in the static map and in turn the global costmap is tracking all the changes in the static map. Once I switch to localization mode, and no more changes are brought to the static map, if i remove one obstacle from the environment and my robot is close to it (the robot has 4 cameras as observation sources) I would expect for that obstacle to be cleared from the global costmap, at least as long as the cameras can see that it is not there, even though the obstacle would still be marked in the static map. I believe that the issue is related to some poor configuration of the move_base costmaps but no new combination of parameters or new configuration seems to lead me to the desired behavior.

I am attaching here the current configuration I use for my costmaps and some screenshots with the issue.

**Costmaps configuration:**

costmap_common.yaml

```
footprint: [[-0.475, -0.34], [-0.475, 0.34], [0.475, 0.34], [0.475, -0.34]]
footprint_padding: 0.02

robot_base_frame: base_footprint
update_frequency: 8.0  # Default 4.0
publish_frequency: 6.0  # Default 3.0
transform_tolerance: 0.5

resolution: 0.05

#always_send_full_costmap: true

inflation:
    inflation_radius: 1.0

#layer definitions
static:
    map_topic: /map
    subscribe_to_updates: true

virtual_walls_static_map:
    map_topic: /virtual_walls_map
    subscribe_to_updates: true
    use_maximum: true  
    track_unknown_space: false 

obstacles_laser:
    observation_sources: ultrasonics_warn ultrasonics_alert camera_1_obstacles camera_2_obstacles camera_3_obstacles camera_4_obstacles camera_1_laser camera_2_laser camera_3_laser camera_4_laser
    camera_1_laser: { data_type: LaserScan, clearing: true, marking: true, topic: /camera_1/laser_scan, obstacle_range: 5.5, raytrace_range: 6.0 }
    camera_2_laser: { data_type: LaserScan, clearing: true, marking: true, topic: /camera_2/laser_scan, obstacle_range: 5.5, raytrace_range: 6.0 }
    camera_3_laser: { data_type: LaserScan, clearing: true, marking: true, topic: /camera_3/laser_scan, obstacle_range: 5.5, raytrace_range: 6.0 }
    camera_4_laser: { data_type: LaserScan, clearing: true, marking: true, topic: /camera_4/laser_scan, obstacle_range: 5.5, raytrace_range: 6.0 }
    camera_1_obstacles: {data_type: PointCloud2, clearing: true, marking: true, topic: /camera_1/obstacles_cloud, obstacle_range: 5.5, raytrace_range: 6.0}
    camera_2_obstacles: {data_type: PointCloud2, clearing: true, marking: true, topic: /camera_2/obstacles_cloud, obstacle_range: 5.5, raytrace_range: 6.0}
    camera_3_obstacles: {data_type: PointCloud2, clearing: true, marking: true, topic: /camera_3/obstacles_cloud, obstacle_range: 5.5, raytrace_range: 6.0}
    camera_4_obstacles: {data_type: PointCloud2, clearing: true, marking: true, topic: /camera_4/obstacles_cloud, obstacle_range: 5.5, raytrace_range: 6.0}
    ultrasonics_warn: {data_type: PointCloud, clearing: false, marking: true, topic: /ultrasonic/warn_point_cloud/combined, obstacle_range: 5.5, raytrace_range: 6.0}
    ultrasonics_alert: {data_type: PointCloud, clearing: false, marking: true, topic: /ultrasonic/alert_point_cloud/combined, obstacle_range: 5.5, raytrace_range: 6.0}
    #laser: {data_type: LaserScan, clearing: true, marking: true, topic: camera/laser_scan, inf_is_valid: true, obstacle_range: 5.5, raytrace_range: 6.0}
    #camera_1_ground: {data_type: PointCloud2, clearing: false, marking: true, topic: /camera_1/ground_cloud, obstacle_range: 5.5, raytrace_range: 6.0}
    #camera_2_ground: {data_type: PointCloud2, clearing: false, marking: true, topic: /camera_2/ground_cloud, obstacle_range: 5.5, raytrace_range: 6.0}
    #camera_3_ground: {data_type: PointCloud2, clearing: false, marking: true, topic: /camera_3/ground_cloud, obstacle_range: 5.5, raytrace_range: 6.0}
    #camera_4_ground: {data_type: PointCloud2, clearing: false, marking: true, topic: /camera_4/ground_cloud, obstacle_range: 5.5, raytrace_range: 6.0}
```

costmap_local.yaml

```
global_frame: map  
rolling_window: true

plugins:
  - {name: virtual_walls_static_map,  type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
  - {name: obstacles_laser,           type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"}
  - {name: inflation,                 type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}
```

costmap_global_static.yaml

```
global_frame: map
rolling_window: false
track_unknown_space: true

plugins:
  - {name: static,                   type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
  - {name: virtual_walls_static_map, type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
  - {name: obstacles_laser,          type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"}
  - {name: inflation,                type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}
```

In the following screenshots from RVIZ I will try to show the current behavior and explain what I would like to happen instead.

As a test environment for replicating this issue i am using the bookstore world from gazebo. In this first screenshot we can already see that the map has been built and the robot is now in localization mode. The robot is now facing a bookshelf which is marked in all the costmaps (only global visible in the screenshot).
[image: image description]

In this second screenshot I have removed the bookshelf in front of the robot from the world but as it can be seen, it is still marked in the global costmap. The bookshelf is still in the static map which the global costmap is tracking but I would expect for the bookshelf to be removed from the global costmap since the cameras can clearly see it is not there anymore. I have also posted a new goal for the planner and the expected behavior would be for it to plan straight through were the obstacle used to be (but since it is still marked in the global costmap, it cannot do so).
[image: image description]\

This issue has been bugging me a lot and I have tried changing multiple parameters in the costmaps configuration but with no success. At this point I am not even sure it is a configuration issue or not, or if the behavior I am looking for is achievable. Any help would be much appreciated! Please let me know if any further information is needed to clarify this issue and feel free to drop any tips below!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/375648/move_base-global-costmap-is-not-updated-when-removing-an-object/obstacle-from-the-environment/) by [geoporus](https://answers.ros.org/users/57112/geoporus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2021-04-07

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2021-04-07**:
Have you seen #q316191?

**Comment by [geoporus](https://answers.ros.org/users/57112/geoporus/) on 2021-04-08**:
Hey @tryan! Thanks for the tip...checking it now to see maybe the information there can help me!

**Comment by [geoporus](https://answers.ros.org/users/57112/geoporus/) on 2021-04-08**:
Coming back with an update, the information in the thread linked above helped me in fixing the issue! Thanks @tryan for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the meantime I have managed to find the solution for my problem by using the information found in [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/316191/static_layer-gets-deleted-by-obstacle_layer-in-global_costmap/) question.

What did it for me was setting the combination method to 0 for the obstacles_laser layer and reordering the layer plugins in both the local and global costmaps. I will add the updated costmap configurations here for future reference for people that might still bump into this issue the same way that I did!

costmap_common.yaml

```
footprint: [[-0.475, -0.34], [-0.475, 0.34], [0.475, 0.34], [0.475, -0.34]]
footprint_padding: 0.02

robot_base_frame: sampo_base_footprint
update_frequency: 8.0  # Default 4.0
publish_frequency: 6.0  # Default 3.0
transform_tolerance: 0.5

resolution: 0.05

#always_send_full_costmap: true

inflation:
    inflation_radius: 1.0

#layer definitions
static:
    map_topic: /map
    subscribe_to_updates: false

virtual_walls_static_map:
    map_topic: /virtual_walls_map
    subscribe_to_updates: true
    use_maximum: true  
    track_unknown_space: false  

obstacles_laser:
    obstacle_range: 5.0
    raytrace_range: 5.0
    combination_method: 0
    observation_sources: ultrasonics_warn ultrasonics_alert camera_1_obstacles camera_2_obstacles camera_3_obstacles camera_4_obstacles camera_1_laser camera_2_laser camera_3_laser camera_4_laser
    camera_1_laser: {data_type: LaserScan, clearing: true, marking: true, topic: /camera_1/laser_scan}
    camera_2_laser: {data_type: LaserScan, clearing: true, marking: true, topic: /camera_2/laser_scan}
    camera_3_laser: {data_type: LaserScan, clearing: true, marking: true, topic: /camera_3/laser_scan}
    camera_4_laser: {data_type: LaserScan, clearing: true, marking: true, topic: /camera_4/laser_scan}
    camera_1_obstacles: {data_type: PointCloud2, clearing: true, marking: true, topic: /camera_1/obstacles_cloud}
    camera_2_obstacles: {data_type: PointCloud2, clearing: true, marking: true, topic: /camera_2/obstacles_cloud}
    camera_3_obstacles: {data_type: PointCloud2, clearing: true, marking: true, topic: /camera_3/obstacles_cloud}
    camera_4_obstacles: {data_type: PointCloud2, clearing: true, marking: true, topic: /camera_4/obstacles_cloud}
    ultrasonics_warn: {data_type: PointCloud, clearing: false, marking: true, topic: /ultrasonic/warn_point_cloud/combined}
    ultrasonics_alert: {data_type: PointCloud, clearing: false, marking: true, topic: /ultrasonic/alert_point_cloud/combined}
    #laser: {data_type: LaserScan, clearing: true, marking: true, topic: camera/laser_scan, inf_is_valid: true, obstacle_range: 5.5, raytrace_range: 6.0}
    #camera_1_ground: {data_type: PointCloud2, clearing: false, marking: true, topic: /camera_1/ground_cloud, obstacle_range: 5.5, raytrace_range: 6.0}
    #camera_2_ground: {data_type: PointCloud2, clearing: false, marking: true, topic: /camera_2/ground_cloud, obstacle_range: 5.5, raytrace_range: 6.0}
    #camera_3_ground: {data_type: PointCloud2, clearing: false, marking: true, topic: /camera_3/ground_cloud, obstacle_range: 5.5, raytrace_range: 6.0}
    #camera_4_ground: {data_type: PointCloud2, clearing: false, marking: true, topic: /camera_4/ground_cloud, obstacle_range: 5.5, raytrace_range: 6.0}
```

costmap_local.yaml

```
local_costmap:
  global_frame: map  
  rolling_window: true

  static_map: false

  plugins:
    - {name: obstacles_laser,           type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"}
    - {name: virtual_walls_static_map,  type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
    - {name: inflation,                 type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}
```

costmap_global_static.yaml

```
global_costmap:
  global_frame: map
  rolling_window: false
  track_unknown_space: true

  plugins:
    - {name: static,                   type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
    - {name: obstacles_laser,          type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"}
    - {name: virtual_walls_static_map, type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
    - {name: inflation,                type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}
```

Thanks @tryan for pointing me to the thread that helped me solve the issue! Hope this answer will help others in the future!

---

Originally posted by [geoporus](https://answers.ros.org/users/57112/geoporus/) with karma: 51 on 2021-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1